# syspolicyd uses a lot of CPU on a machine that runs a "self compiled" command line process that takes a lot of CPU

Tags: performance, cpu, macos

I run a bash script that feeds a C++ binary (downloaded from Github and compiled locally) with thousands of files. This C++ binary is extremely CPU-heavy. For performance reasons I run six parallel instances of this script (this is on a Macbook Pro 16" with Intel CPU).

No other significant applications are running (e.g. Calender and BBEdit are loaded but their CPU usage is negligible, and they should be non-problematic from a security point of view (syspolicyd is part of Gatekeeper)), yet syspolicyd uses 30-40 % CPU.

**I am wondering if syspolicyd scans this C++ binary constantly or something like that?**

More information:

- I just (a few hours ago) upgraded the machine to the latest version of MacOS. I read somewhere that syspolicyd might have to rescan the whole machine after an upgrade?
- The script is just a wrapper to feed all files in a directory to the C++ binary. In other words, this binary quits when a file is processed and is then launched again when it is fed a new file. The binary is also quite memory intensive, it loads a 3 GB database on each launch an uses about 3,6 GB of memory (according to Activity Monitor). Could it be that syspolicyd scans this 3 GB database each time it is loaded (each execution takes about 10 minutes and since I run 6 parallel processes the binary is launched about once every 1,5 minute - does syspolicyd need to scan the 3 GB database every 1,5 minutes?)

The binary and its database are absolutely safe - if the problem is that they are scanned on every launch, could I somehow disable syspolicyd for certain files or processes?

Any other ideas why syspolicyd takes a lot of CPU?

Comment: Is this C++ binary long-running or short-running? (i.e. how often is a new process running that binary started?)

Comment: The C++ binary rarely runs for less than 5 minutes, and regularly runs for an hour or more.